# backbone collection not popuplating default value for model created from array of object

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I tried to create a collection from array of object and it is creating but it doesn't have default values of the models for eg.

```
class Message extends Backbone.Model
   defaults: 
     name: 'test'
class Messages extends Backbone.Collection
   model: Message

new Messages([{age:45}]) # has no name attr in model
new Messages [new Message age:45]  #has name attr
```

thanks

Comment: even the urlRoot: '/messages' would not be part of the model

Comment: What is `default` and why would Backbone care about it? [`defaults`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) OTOH will be used. Once that is fixed, everything seems to work fine with the latest Backbone: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Pvw2c/

Comment: I think that was problem.